# vcs not setup correctly while I install ROS using source

Tags: ros, rosinstall, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed : http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

I use the command

```
 rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"
```

And after a while it appears:

```
 Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.2.8  to /media/634bad56-5543-40fe-843b-cd31f4a95dba/home/sam/ros/simulator_gazebo
 svn: OPTIONS of 'https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.2.8': Could not read status line: Secure connection truncated (https://code.ros.org)
 ERROR: Failed to install tree '/media/634bad56-5543-40fe-843b-cd31f4a95dba/home/sam/ros/simulator_gazebo'
  vcs not setup correctly
```

My ubuntu: uname -a

```
 Linux sam-desktop 2.6.32-25-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 16 19:48:22 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

How to solve it?
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10682/vcs-not-setup-correctly-while-i-install-ros-using-source/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"Secure connection truncated" sounds like a network hiccup; what happens if you just run it again?

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-22**:
Passed. It works! Thank you~~